# How to Eliminate Nginx from the Production Stack via using Cloudflare as a substitutable Reverse Proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, host, cloudflare

Is it possible to use "cloudflare" as a reverse proxy for hosting several websites on the same host machine but on different ports?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare can replace some of the features of Nginx, specifically:

- Caching resources
- Rate limiting and protecting your website
- Redirecting access to your website to another server

But you still need Nginx or another web server for the following tasks:

- Handling the TCP connections between Cloudflare and the server which generates the response (+ HTTPS should be used)
- Generating the actual response, via FastCGI (PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.) or just delivering a file/resource (server and location blocks in Nginx)
- Setting the correct headers for the response, for caching and content type (Cloudflare relies on these)

Cloudflare does not support sending your requests to specific ports on the origin host - but that would still not help you much, because Cloudflare has a very specific feature set, and generating responses is not part of them, which is why you need a web server.

If you want to reduce the work needed to maintain Nginx, you can restrict Nginx to only reply to requests by Cloudflare and do the rate limiting and some other tasks in Cloudflare.

Comment: thank you for your answer; ofcourse it is fair to assume that the host machine will be having servers, each server mounted on a specific port. and I was hoping that cloudflare could help me redirect a request coming form a specific domain, to a specific port on the host machine, hence acting as a reverse proxy.

From your answer I am assuming that it is not possible to have cloudflare do that?

Comment: Cloudflare is already a reverse proxy - but you still need Nginx as a web server. When your server receives a request, the web server handles the TCP connection, HTTPS connection, finding the file/resource to deliver and sending it back to Cloudflare as a valid HTTP response.

If you are only using Nginx as a reverse proxy you can remove it and use Cloudflare for that, but if you use Nginx as a web server (actually serving requests and files), you cannot replace that with Cloudflare.

Comment: That makes sense! yet the problem presented here is serving *multiple* web applications from the same host machine. Thats what I am after...

Comment: That's no problem with Nginx - or any other web server software. That is basically what web servers do, they can serve as many web applications / domains as you want. In Nginx you can define different domains in server blocks. You do not need different ports - Nginx can handle everything with one port.